# Network manager default configuration file?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

What is the default network manager configuration file in Ubuntu? When I install it on top of the default /etc/network/interfaces network setup on a server it overrides the configuration in some file as the network stops functioning,

I've tried to change my /etc/network/interfaces before starting the network-manager but it doesn't seem like it's using the settings from that file.

By default it's a static/manual configuration in the /etc/network/interfaces
but if I remove that or keep it, network manager will use its own settings
and the network will no longer work, how would i make nm work in conjunction with the settings I already had? Thanks.

My default current plugins and settings in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf is:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

wouldn't changing the variable of managed decide whether what configuration to use?

EDIT:
So far I have tried to put this in my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
But it doesn't work, when I had no address and ip set (it's static)
then it worked for a few seconds at startup and then stopped working.
How do I set up a proper ip static configuration in NetworkManager.conf if poss?

```
[connection]
id=Main ens3
uuid=myuuid
type=802-3-ethernet
autoconnect=true

[ipv4]
method=manual
address-data=myip
gateway=mygateway

[802-3-ethernet]
mac-address=mymacaddress
```

UPDATE: I tried to put only

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

in my NetworkManager.conf and ignored the rest of the settings I applied so it'll use the settings provided in /etc/network/interfaces, then when I reboot and start NetworkManager it only works the first few seconds and then the Network stops. There must be something in NetworkManager that is conflicting with the settings provided in /etc/network/interfaces, if so, which is it? If I would use

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

NetworkManager would use its own settings but not in this case as stated here [ifupdown](https://linux.die.net/man/5/networkmanager.conf).

Comment: Ubuntu currently

Answer (score 2):

Everything is relatively depending on your distribution.

Reading `man(5)` for `NetworkManager.conf` you can see, that it's configuration is placed on `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, when talking about CentOS for example.

There you have bunch of plugins and management options for network interfaces management. By default it uses `ifcfg-rh` plugin for CentOS. It means that, more or less, its configuration is based on `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` scripts.

Talking about Debian, I can see that network interfaces are handled by `NetworkManager`, iff they are not specified in `/etc/network/interfaces` [[Debian Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.network-config.html)]. Hence you specified interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, `NM` has nothing to do here. There is no conjuction here. You can use `nmcli` or `nmtui` to manage interfaces easily with `NetworkManager`.
`nmtui` is much more friendly.

Comment: These are my current plugins in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: ifupdown,keyfile,ofono and managed=false wouldn't changing the variable of managed decide whether what configuration to use? So I cannot force NetworkManager to use my /etc/network/interfaces file it looks like? So I have to remove my interfaces from /etc/network/interfaces and then add a similiar connection by using nmtui. Ok I got it.

Comment: Nmtui or nmcli doesn't seem to work while network-manager is off. How would i go to do it then, change the NetworkManager.conf file if it's possible there?, Ok @roaima.

Comment: @S.L The manual configuration should be done from the `/etc/network/interfaces`  the NetworkManager.conf is used by NM see `man interfaces`